# Saving history of usage to offer suggestions

Tags: search, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, string-matching

- I have a small extension that perform local search.
- It searches for the files matching that name in the local company files list and then opens a page with the results.
- The extension has a text box where users type in the query.

The **problem** is that if I click the extension again and want to do a query that I already did previously, I need to type it out again.

- I want the textbox to save history, and show suggestions when I start typing a new query.

How can I do this? The suggestion matching can be a very simple string matching, nothing fancy. But how/where canI save the history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about standard browser's autocomplete then I don't think there is a way to programmatically create it.

You can build your own with jQuery's [autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete),  for example. You will just feed it previous queries and it will do the rest.

To store previous queries you can use [`localStorage`](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-learning-about-html5-local-storage/), which you would need to access from a background page.